# Problems with Sharepoint 2010, Visio Data Provider and Operations Manager 2007 R2

Tags: sharepoint, scom, visio

I'm in the process of setting up rack diagrams using Visio 2010 Premium pulling in data from System Centre Operations Manager 2007 R2 using the add in. I'm trying to publish the diagram to a Sharepoint 2010 site.

Now it all works fine until I try to enable data refreshing from the Sharepoint site, it errors with...

> An exception occurred communicating
>   with the Operations Manager RMS.
>   Please contact your system
>   administrator

I suspect this has something to do with permissions, however I have added the service account that's running the Visio Data Provider as a read only operator on OpsMgr as advised in the documentation, as well as adding the two sharepoint web farm computer accounts to the OpsMgr Administrator group just to be doubly sure.

Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong? There are threads on the subject on Technet but it doesn't give a particularly specific resolution.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/operationsmanagergeneral/thread/f64be3fe-abb1-44d7-8376-3fcd9eabaf07

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution to this after doing all that I had done above was to wait. I suspect replication/propagation time is why this continued to happen for a while after making the changes.